# Bug: Can Vote >1 Time to Close a Question

Tags: bug, status-norepro, vote-to-close

I voted to close this question: [textbox does not accept a value in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167213/textbox-does-not-accept-a-value-in-asp-net) about an hour ago. After viewing some subsequent comments, I was wondering if I could take back my vote, figuring this might be a possibility given the other changes on the site.

Now, I've managed to vote twice to close this question.

EDIT: I was indeed able to retract my more recent close vote.

Comment: Got an idea, let me test... nope - multi tabs don't let you vote more than once. I'd say no-repro.

Comment: Agreed. Withdrawn.

Answer (score 6):

Vote retraction was recently implemented and you're not supposed to be able to cast a second close vote.

Right now the post timeline only shows one close vote from you and it shows that it's been retracted. The two close votes on the question right now are from other users.

What exactly happened when you went to vote to close again?

Comment: It just showed me another "vote to close" screen as if I never voted on it.

Comment: I'm going to take the approach that it's more likely that I'm remembering things wrong than there being a bug with the site. Especially if you're saying that the two close votes currently there are from other members. I *was* hesitant to close it. Perhaps I never hit the final "Close" button.

Comment: So you see all this info in [the good old timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19167213/timeline)? And I always thought you have cool control panels and tools for this stuff!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, there's a different (and currently mod-only, with parts that are employee-only) timeline view. Because life would be far too easy if we didn't overload any terms.

Comment: @Anna oh, that's nice - guess you have link to that view, us mortals have to manually construct the URL to reach the meager timeline we get!

Comment: Anyway based on the OP comments looks like this can be safely tagged [meta-tag:status-norepro]. :)